# NoticeやWarningログをWEB上に表示したい

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHPを利用した開発環境で、NoticeやWarningログをWEB上に表示したいのですが、どうしても巧く行きません。

**実行環境**
CakePHP 2.2
PHP 5.3

**確認、実行した内容**
・phpinfoでのチェック
display_errors項目が、Local Valueではoff、Master Valueではonになっています。

・php.ini
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
上記設定でコメント外れています

・httpd.conf
php_flag display_errors on
こちらをconfファイルの上部あるいは最下部に入れてもエラーは表示されず

・htaccessファイル
CakePHPソース内のhtaccessを確認しましたが、PHPエラーを非表示にする記述は見当たらず、また、php_flag display_errors onを設定しても変化なし。

・CakePHP側
core.phpのDEBUGモードを1ないし2ないし3に設定しても画面には表示されず。
logフォルダ下のログファイルには、NoticeやWarningは記録されていますが、これを画面上で確認できるようにしたい……。

・PHPファイルへの記述
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
これをPHPファイル頭に記述しても画面には表示されず。

ここまで確認したのですが、ログファイルには記録されても、どうしても画面にエラーが表示されません。
手詰まりになってしまったのですが、他に考えられる原因は無いでしょうか……。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

CakePHPでは `Configure::write()` メソッドで `debug` オプションを書き換える際に、
 `display_errors` も更新します。

CakePHP2系: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php#L168
CakePHP3系:
 https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/917f876168e4b5af2a787f3d17b7659c1f4cb679/src/Core/Configure.php#L99

`Configure::write('debug', false)` の記述があれば、 `display_errors=0` となります。

2系であれば、`Config/core.php`、 3系であれば、`config/app.php` の `debug` の値を確認してください。
ただし、それ以外の場所で、Configure::writeメソッドにより変更されている場合もあります。また、3系ではコードに記述のある通り、`DEBUG`という環境変数に依存します。

なお、開発環境であれば、 debug=true で問題ありませんが、本番環境では debug=false に忘れずに変更しましょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
CakePHPは2系（2.2）を使用しています。
debugモードはCore内Configure::write('debug', 2);等試しているのですが、表示できずにいます。（数字は1～3全部試しました）
他に同記述が無いか探してみます！